# Different Excel notifications on opening very similar files

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2013, notifications, security-warning

Template files were prepared and sent to users. The files are essentially identical (both have identical VBA code, the same passwords on VBA, sheets and workbook structure), but it's evident that one user changed the file somehow so that now I am unable to read it automatically using VBA and ADODB.

When opening manually, the (bad) file which I cannot read opens with these notifications:
[image: microsoft excel security notice]
[image: automatic update of links has been disabled - Options]

While the good file which *can* be read opens with this notification:
[image: automatic update of links has been disabled - enable content]

The first file security notice says something about macros. But both files have the same macros... However, after manually opening both files I notice that macros do not work on the first (bad) file, and they do work on the good one.

Does someone understand the difference between these notifications, why do I get them different?

Maybe adding the location of both files (the location is the same) to the trusted locations list would solve the problem. But I want to understand the cause if it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find an answer I needed to compare in detail both files. I used a brilliant tool of Office 2013 - **Spreadsheet Compare 2013**. It revealed that one of the things which was different in both files was workbook structure protection. In the "bad" file the **workbook structure was protected** with a password and macros were not running because of this. I removed this password, saved the file, and then everything started working after restarting the file. And this essentially was the reason why I received different notifications.